# How to handle events that happened on different page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a **UWP** Project with 2 pages so far. The `MainPage.xaml` is the basic layout of the app ( hamburger menu, search bar, etc.). The other part of this MainPage contains a frame into which the other page `LandingPage.xaml` is loaded. I want to capture the user input from an AutosuggestBox in the MainPage.xaml and show the results on LandingPage.xaml ( which is in a frame present inside MainPage.xaml).

I tried inheriting the MainPage, but that's not allowed.

Comment: Are you using MVVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Marian's answer would certainly work, I think it's far from being 'clean' or 'good' code.

First and foremost, you should implement the MVVM pattern in your UWP apps (if you don't do it already) and use a dependency injection framework for that. A very basic, easy to understand one is MVVMLight, while a more sophisticated framework of choice could be Autofac. I advise you to start with the former, it's much quicker to wrap your head around it first.

In MVVM there's a concept that solves just your problem: messengers. I wouldn't like to get into the details here, since there already a lot of very good resources about this written by much smarter people than me. For example this article from the author of MVVMLight himself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx (I know it's from 2013 and speaks about Windows 8, but fear not, the concepts are just the same.)

The idea is that distinct ViewModels shouldn't have strict dependencies on each other - it makes unit testing (which is one of the main points of doing MVVM in the first place) hard. So in your case, you should have two ViewModels: MainViewModel and LandingViewModel. One for MainPage, and one for LandingPage, respectively. Now you should implement a handler in MainPage's code-behind for AutoSuggestBox's QuerySubmitted event and call a function in MainViewModel. In that function, you would instantiate a new message with the string coming from your AutoSuggestBox (which you can acquire either from doing data binding to it or through the event handler of QuerySubmitted, it's up to you) and send it via the Messenger. In LandingViewModel, you would subscribe to this exact message and then it's again just a matter of few lines to display the received message through data binding on LandingPage.

I know it looks like a lot of hassle for just something very basic like this, especially if you compare it to Marian's straight to the point solution. But trust me, in the long run writing clean code, nicely separated, easily unit testable ViewModels will make up for the additional effort that you have to put into them initially to make them work. After such a system is set up between two ViewModels, adding a third (which I assume you'll need to do soon) is absolutely trivial and can be done very quickly.

Comment: Definitely and ephatically disagree. MVVM is a buzzword and while there are many cases where it has its advantages, there are equally many -- smaller projects, not in team, etc --- where it only introduces a lot of unnecessary complexity. Even in those cases, there are other approaches that provide the necessary separation without incurring the extra abstractions of MVVM. Especially if you also suggest complete frameworks. Classic example of everything looking like a nail...

Comment: I agree with you in general, but according to my experience, developing a XAML-based application without the MVVM pattern becomes painful rather quickly if you go a bit further than the template projects in Visual Studio. On top of that, the framework I suggested in this (now 3 years old) answer is/was a pretty barebones one. It really doesn't have much else than the minimum required code for proper unit testing (DI, IoC), a ViewModel base class and a Messenger implementation. I think this is rather far from "introducing a lot of unnecessary complexity" in case of UWP.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using MVVM I'd suggest adding `x:FieldModifier="public"` on the `AutoSuggestBox` and add a public static property to MainPage to store its instance.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public static MainPage Current { get; private set; }

public MainPage()
{
    Current = this;
    // Rest of your code in ctor
}
```

Then you can access it using

```
string text = MainPage.Current.NameOfYourAutoSuggestBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple message passing mechanism of your own, like this:

```
public class Messages {
  public static Messages Instance { get; } = new Messages();

  private readonly List<Subscription> subscriptions;

  private Messages() {
    subscriptions = new List<Subscription>();
  }

  public void Send<T>(T message) {
    var msgType = message.GetType();
    foreach (var sub in subscriptions)
      if (sub.Type.IsAssignableFrom(msgType))
        sub.Handle(message);
  }

  public Guid Subscribe<T>(Action<T> action) {
    var key = Guid.NewGuid();
    lock (subscriptions) {
      subscriptions.Add(new Subscription(typeof(T), key, action));
    }
    return key;
  }

  public void Unsubscribe(Guid key) {
    lock (subscriptions) {
      subscriptions.RemoveAll(sub => sub.Key == key);
    }
  }

  public bool IsSubscribed(Guid key) {
    lock (subscriptions) {
      return subscriptions.Any(sub => sub.Key == key);
    }
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    subscriptions.Clear();
  }
}

internal sealed class Subscription {
  internal Guid Key { get; }
  internal Type Type { get; }
  private object Handler { get; }

  internal Subscription(Type type, Guid key, object handler) {
    Type = type;
    Key = key;
    Handler = handler;
  }

  internal void Handle<T>(T message) {
    ((Action<T>)Handler).Invoke(message);
  }
}
```

It's small and simple but it allows the subscription of different messages in parallel, separated by message type. You can subscribe, in a case similar to yours, with:

```
Messages.Instance.Subscribe<TextChangeArgs>(OnTextChanged);
```

and your other pages can send their messages using:

```
Messages.Instance.Send(new TextChangeArgs(...));
```

From all subscribers, only those interested in this specific message type will receive the message. You can (and, of course, should) also unsubscribe. Some more error handling could also be necessary in a real world scenario.

If necessary, you can add extra functionality like throttling easily (to avoid too many consecutive messages in a given time period).